# From binary file to int Python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read binary file with encryption key and load it to ciphertable (always 64bytes to 8x8 table). Tried to google without results. I'm sure the solution is simple but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Error:

> self.**cphtbl**[i][j] = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big')
>   TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

My code:

```
...
def createCipherTable(self):        
    keyFile = open(self.keyFilePath, "rb")
    self.__cphtbl__ = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] *8
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            byte = keyFile.read(1)
            self.__cphtbl__[i][j] = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big')
....
```

I also tried:

```
int(from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big')
```

but the output is:

```
NameError: name 'from_bytes' is not defined
```

Also tried:

```
self.__cphtbl__[i][j].from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big')
```

But then it says:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Try `int(from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big'))`

Comment: I've tried. Still the same error...

Comment: Are you sure? Can you tell me what `from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big')` returns?

Comment: `self.__cphtbl__[i][j] = int(from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big'))
NameError: name 'from_bytes' is not defined`

Comment: What is `from_bytes` ? Error says `from_bytes` is not defined

Comment: its a built in function - it returns byte value of byte-type object... `int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder)` and `int.to_bytes(value, byteorder)`. And Error says `from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big')` is not defined... it isn't. Its an int class method. Also tried `int(int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big'))`

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: `>>> Python 3.6.3`

Comment: Is it a script? Can you try executing it like `python3 script.py`? If not, can you `import sys` and `print sys.version` in the file ?

Comment: I'm using `python3 myscripts.py`

Comment: Your `__cphtbl__` is not a 2D array

Comment: @ThatBird Ok :). Silly Me. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `self.__cphtbl__` is a `1d` array, not `2d`.

If u want `2d` array do this:

```
...
def createCipherTable(self):        
    keyFile = open(self.keyFilePath, "rb")
    self.__cphtbl__ = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] * 8 # Here is change [[]] * n instead of [] * n
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            byte = keyFile.read(1)
            self.__cphtbl__[i][j] = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder = 'big')
....
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is your `__cphtbl__` is not a 2d array and you are trying to

`cphtbl[i][j] = int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder = 'big')`

hence the error. You need to create a 2d array and it will work as expected

To create a 2d array, you could simply do -

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] *8
```